# Adding Columns to Multiple Tables in SQL

Tags: sql

I just created a database and then added a couple of hundred tables with a script like this:

```
CREATE TABLE CapBond
(
    [timestamp] varchar(50),
    [Reward] varchar(50),
    [Award] varchar(50),
    [Fact] varchar(50)
)

CREATE TABLE Values
(
    [timestamp] varchar(50),
    [Name] varchar(50),
    [Test] varchar(50),
    [Read] varchar(50),
    [Parameters] varchar(50)
)
```

I realize I forgot to add two columns to each table. One for the PK and one for an FK that points back to a 'master' table.

Is there an easy way to insert columns without having to drop the DB and recreate it? Preferably with the columns inserted as the first two columns in the table?

Comment: What database??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In mysql you have the alter table command  for this purpose. Check out this page for more detailed explanation 
https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-alter-table-add-column/ .

And here is the solution for the ordering of the columns 
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-add-column/

Comment: I'm assuming that would be the same for MS SQL?  It's been so long since I've done any DB work, I can't remember any commands.  I do recall "ALTER TABLE", however, I couldn't begin to remember the syntax.  I'll give it a shot.  Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to specify the position of the new column?

Comment: For the position I am not sure bit the syntax is similar to the mysql one in mssql as well https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-alter-table-add-column/